# How to override class of a module?

Tags: magento-1.8, overrides

I have installed a module which overrides a core class of magento.

```
class Namespace_Module_Model_Sales_Quote_Address_Total_Profile_Subtotal
    extends Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Subtotal
```

As you can see the Subtotal class of sales module is extended.
Now I want to extend

```
Namespace_Module_Model_Sales_Quote_Address_Total_Profile_Subtotal
```

I tried some solutions from google but nothing is working.

My main motive is to override function `_initItem` of class `app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Address/Total/Subtotal.php`

And want override/remove functionality of function `_initItem` of `Namespace_Module_Model_Sales_Quote_Address_Total_Profile_Subtotal`

I am using Magento 1.8.1.0

Please help.

**UPDATE**

```
class Namespace_Module_Model_Sales_Quote_Address_Total_Profile_Subtotal
    extends Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Subtotal
{
    protected $_canAddAmountToAddress = false;
    protected $_itemRowTotalKey = 'rt';
    private $_originalProductPrice = null;

    protected function _initItem($address, $item)
    {
        if ($item instanceof Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Item) {
            $quoteItem = $item->getAddress()->getQuote()->getItemById($item->getQuoteItemId());
        } else {
            $quoteItem = $item;
        }
        $product = $quoteItem->getProduct();
        $isReduction=false;
        $product->setCustomerGroupId($quoteItem->getQuote()->getCustomerGroupId());

        if ($item->getQuote()->getIsSuperMode()) {
            if (!$product) {
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            if (!$product || !$product->isVisibleInCatalog()) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        if (null === $this->_originalProductPrice) {
            $this->_originalProductPrice = $product->getPrice();
        }

        $profileTypeOption = Mage::helper('module/quote')->getProfileTypeOptionFromQuoteItem($item);
        $profileItem = Mage::getModel('module/profile_item')->load($profileTypeOption);
        $isReduction=false;
        $itemId=$profileItem->getData('profile_type_id');
        if(Mage::helper('core')->isModuleEnabled('MyModule')){
            $isReduction=true;
            if(!$product->getQty())
                $qty=Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getItemsQty();
            else
                $qty=$product->getQty();
            $quantityArray=array();
            $totalOccurrence=Mage::getModel('profile/price')->getTotalOccurrence($itemId);
            $totalBags=$qty*$totalOccurrence;
            $reductionPrice=Mage::getModel('profile/price')->getReducedPrice($totalBags,$product->getId());
        }
        if($isReduction)
            $product->setPrice($reductionPrice);
        else
            $product->setPrice($profileItem->getData('regular_price'));
        $product->setPrice($reductionPrice);
        $product->setSpecialPrice(null);
        $finalPrice = $product->getFinalPrice($quoteItem->getQty());
        $item->setPrice($finalPrice);
        $item->setBaseOriginalPrice($finalPrice);
        $item->calcRowTotal();
        $this->_addAmount($item->getRowTotal());
        $this->_addBaseAmount($item->getBaseRowTotal());
        $address->setTotalQty($address->getTotalQty() + $item->getQty());
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: show code of Namespace_Module_Model_Sales_Quote_Address_Total_Profile_Subtotal

Comment: Hello Amit, Please see my update

Comment: When you say you want to extend the class, do you mean you want to rewrite it? It's not clear from the question.

Comment: Yes I want to rewrite it. And want to modify and use function _initItem

Answer (score 1):

To rewrite a rewrite you must define a rewrite of the *original class* in your module and make your module depend on the module with the existing rewrite. This way, your rewrite definition overrides the original rewrite definition when the config.xml files are merged.

To define the dependency, edit your file in `app/etc/modules/`:

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <NS_Module>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Other_Extension />
            </depends>
        </NS_Module>
    </modules>
</config>
```

And then let your rewritten class `extend` the rewritten class from `Other_Extension`.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to chain these rewrites.

i.e.

Create new module, create a class that inherits from the Original Module's class, e.g.

```
    class Newmodule_Module_Model_Sales_Quote_Address_Total_Profile_Subtotal 
        extends Namespace_Module_Model_Sales_Quote_Address_Total_Profile_Subtotal{

....
```

Then remove the rewrite from the original module's config.xml file.

Now add a new rewrite to your new module's config xml file that overwrites the Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Subtotal class

Comment: I don't want to edit original module files. That's why need a rewrite logic.

Answer (score 0):

You can override it using `config.xml`.

Specify your custom subtotal class by path `global>sales>total>subtotal`.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    ***
    <global>
        ***
        <sales>
            <quote>
                <totals>
                    <subtotal>
                        <class>namespace_module/sales_quote_address_total_profile_subtotal</class>
                    </subtotal>
                </totals>
            </quote>
        </sales>
        ***
    </global>
    ***
</config>
```